# modifying script to show inside file (txt, bat, csv, etc)

Tags: php, directory-listing

im using Evoluted Directory listing to show all file inside directory and i want to modify it for my need,
 here's some screenshot :

[image: 1. Main Evoluted Directory listing page]

then, what i want is change what is showed in "last modified" table 

[image: 2. i want to modify this]

not to show last modified date and time, but show content inside txt, bat, csv file listed there.

[image: 3. content inside txt file]

here's source code of evoluted directory listing i've used

[Evoluted Directory listing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TS4jvY2W8FMBRavzAW5b7FyNqoH05ULi/view?usp=sharing)

this script im guessing that showing "last modified content"

```
<th class="text-right sm-hidden">
<a href="<?php echo $listing->sortUrl('name'); ?>">Last Modified <span class="<?php echo $listing->sortClass('name'); ?>"></span></a>
</th>
```

and im using this script to show content of txt, bat, csv file is

```
<?php
echo nl2br(file_get_contents( "filename.php" )); 
?>
```

i really need help to teach me to modify those script.

Comment: Inside you file_get_contents you will likely need to pass it both the directory path and the file name of each file in the list from the $listing object.

Comment: thank you tristan, i've found the answer, here the solution <br></br> from this <td class="text-right sm-hidden"><?php echo date('M jS Y \a\t g:ia', $file['modified']); ?></td> to <br></br> <td class="text-right sm-hidden"><?php echo nl2br(file_get_contents($file['name'])); ?></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
<td class="text-right sm-hidden"><?php echo date('M jS Y \a\t g:ia', $file['modified']); ?></td> 
<br></br>to <br></br>
<td class="text-right sm-hidden"><?php echo nl2br(file_get_contents($file['name'])); ?></td>
```